# CMake not identifying asm compiler

Tags: assembly, cmake

I'm trying to build a library with CMake and process some files with Clang compiler. I need to process some assembler files so I enabled the use of asm language.

I have not started to process the files yet I just want to check if cmake identifies the compilers properly. When I run cmake I get the following output:

```
The ASM compiler identification is unknown
-- Found assembler: /opt/tricore/ctc/bin/astc
-- Warning: Did not find file Compiler/-ASM
```

What I did:
- ran my root CmakeLists.txt which processes a .cmake script which sets the compilers like this:
  set(TARGET_COMPILER "Clang")

```
CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER("/usr/bin/clang-3.8" Clang)
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER("/usr/bin/clang-3.8" Clang)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER "/opt/tricore/ctc/bin/astc")
```

- Then in the CmakeLists.txt file I enable the use of asm language like this:

  set(can_use_assembler TRUE)
     enable_language(CXX C ASM)

When running cmake the resulted output is the one I mentioned at the begining of the post. I'm confused as the cmake says it does not recognize asm compiler identification then it says assembler was found at some path and then it says it did not find "Compiler/-ASM". So did it or did it not find the asm compiler?

The compilers are not local they come from a docker image I'm using.

Please tell me if possible if I need to do something else so I won't have any issues when I will process the asm files later on.

Thank you for reading!

Comment: What assembler is astc? I have never seen this one before.

Comment: no ideea. some assembler used in a project I work I guess. It was used for another controller as well :D. I'm not very familiar with asm and compilers for it I just need to integrate some files in a library

Comment: Note that assembly is “assembled,” not “compiled.” I know, cmake does it wrong, too, but it's really confusing if you refer to an “assembly compiler.”

Comment: Ok. I have noticed in another example those warnings are still there but the project builds just fine. I hope it will not impact my work as well.

Comment: did you ever figure out how to resolve this?  have similar issue.